# Google Play Dev Console automation of creating a new app

Tags: android, fastlane

I would like to know how to automate creating a new app for Google Play Store. I know that it's possible to generate screenshots, create the `apk`, upload listing information etc. But how can I **create** the app initially? I want to create with a new package and all. Is there a way to automate this?

I read the fastlane documentation as well as the code here:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-publisher-api/tree/master/v2/python

I also read the documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/#publishing

So far i'm not finding anything for *creating* a new package name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official Google API doesn't allow creating of new applications.
More information on GitHub

- https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/4215
- https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/3740
- https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/3694